# Surveys in probability? In the current literature sense

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

I mostly come from an economics background so when I want to find where the current state of knowledge is in specific fields I look for surveys. These are basically primers so that a researcher can be up to date with the basic logic of the subject and how the latest research are related.

Example:
https://www.bostonfed.org/economic/wp/wp2010/wp1003.pdf

My question is, does something similar exist for probability theory? How are they broken down?

Comment: If they exist; could links be provided please?